# Revert rpm installation on %post failed

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

In %post, I am running few tests that will validate the rpm installation.
But If tests got failed or post script failed, How can I revert the rpm installation ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't really and you shouldn't.

You *should* be asserting everything you possibly can via `Requires: lines in your spec file to prevent you from even getting that far.

`%post` is much too late to abort. All your files have already been put on disk/etc.

You can disable yourself so you don't run but that's about it.

If these are things that you really can't allow to fail then the best you can do is test during `%pre` and abort there (but even that is evil).

Comment: How can you test during `%pre`?  That's a chicken and the egg problem.

Comment: Curious how it's "too late" to roll-back if `%post` fails. Of course, the installer knows what it's done so far and can revert, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is the hack I used in `%post` to roll-back:

```
if [ ! -d %{basedeploymentpath} ]; then
  echo "ERROR: %{basedeploymentpath} does not exist or is inaccessible. I will uninstall myself."
  rpm -ev ${APP_NAME} &
  exit 1
fi
```

In the above snippet, if variable `%{basedeploymentpath}`, which represents a directory, is not found, then call `rpm -ev` on the name of the package, using the `&` to fork the process. The `%post` script exits with code `1` upon the condition mentioned.

If the install process is then run at the command line (`rpm -ivh`) and the error condition exists at post-install, this result will appear: `warning: %post(...) scriptlet failed, exit status 1`

It is an ugly hack but it works. **NOTE**: the exit status of the `rpm -ivh` command will still appear as successful (exit `0`) if you execute `echo $?` after running the `rpm -ivh` operation.

Comment: This is at least an answer to the question.

Comment: this will result in a deadlock if the package is installed with, for example, yum